# Not able to create AVD in android studio

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am new to Android. I have just installed Android Studio and created a default project. Now I am trying to create AVD but am not able to create. Ok button is not enabled. Please help.

[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWjd7.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you havent install the system image, please check the following image

> [image]

To start the SDK Manager click the icon of SDK manager from Android Studio, like below,

> [image]

To install this system image, please Open your SDK manager and tick the system image for Android L version ( as you are creating avd for Android L version ), and then install it.

This will load following scree,

> [image]

Comment: Kedarnath : where i found this screen in andriod studio. I think this screen comes when i am using eclips.

Comment: Kedarnath: first of all thank you for replying. while i am trying to install sdk plateform android L Preview there is an error called Failed to create directory C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp.

I do not understand what is the issue while sdk trying to create folder.

Comment: @sam I suggest you to close the eclipse and then perform the updation process.

Comment: i am not using eclipse i an using android studio.

Comment: @sam, ok then please do close your studio when you are updating, because your studio might using that location so, sdk manager can't access it at same time. closing the studio should solve your problem.

Comment: i had done this but nothing happened. Same issue occor.

Comment: I do close my studio and run as administrator. it is keep start running.

Comment: let it download properly first.

Comment: I am using andriod studio. I want to refresh my emulator without re run of my project. how can i acheive this.

Comment: what do you mean by refresh ?

Comment: i have made changes in my code and want to check what happen using emulator. but i have to reload emulator. its time talking and my emulator running very slow.

Comment: Then you need to re-run your application, rather than re-launching your emulator.

Comment: Each time you run the application, it automatically refreshes the emulator with new updated app.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have system images installed for `Android (L) Preview`. [Use this](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html) link to setup or use the Android SDK manager for downloading the Android-L system images.

Answer (score 0):

Change target for your AVD [see](https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) try target which matches your application. see points in link.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the permissions on the SDK folder are set correctly. You will need write permission.