# Not able to open AVD in Android studio 3.1.1

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have created a **Virtual Device** using **Android studio 3.1.1**.

**Steps :**
1. Go to tools
2. Select AVD manager.
3. A new Window will pop up.
4. Click on create virtual Device
5. Then I'm selecting Phone in category (Pixel 5.0 1080*1920 xxhdpi)
6. Click on Next then I'm selecting Nougat 7.0 API level 24 ABI x86 and target Android 7.0 (Google APIs)
7. Click on Next and then Click on finish.
8. Click on Green button under Action tab but nothing works.

I've already check this SO post : [Not able to create AVD in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738692/not-able-to-create-avd-in-android-studio)

In that post it's mentioned that : The problem is that you haven't **install the system image**. So I tried to **install** that but not able to do so.

Here is the screen shot of details of AVD for Pixel  [image]

How can I install/set the value of CPU/ABI field.